# JPA: Object is not a known Entity type. Completely confused as to how to configure a Spring web app with a modular domain (persistence) project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I am creating a web application using the Spring framework and am trying to do so in a modular fashion. Using NetBeans, I have 2 projects: one containing my application logic, and another containing my actual web application.
In my domain application, I have my DAO using JPA, and have it tested there as well. Now the problem arises when I'm trying to reuse these classes in my Spring module. I am using Maven for both projects and have added a dependency to my domain project in my Spring module. I'm copletely confused as to how to configure this all, this is the first time I'm making such an application, in fact, using Spring and JPA as well. The weird thing as well is, when I first start up the server when my pc has rebooted, it will work, but subsequent reboots of the server will result in the JPA-layer not working anymore.

This is an error when I'm trying to persist my object:

> Object: com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.domain.League@19f is not a known entity type.

I've tried taking the JAR for my persistence module and putting it in my web app's `WEB-INF/lib` folder, but then I get the following error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named LoLWithBuddiesPU

**persistence.xml** which resides in `LoLWithBuddies/src/main/resources/META-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="LoLWithBuddiesPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.domain.League</class>
<class>com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.domain.Membership</class>
<class>com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.domain.Player</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LoLWithBuddies;create=true"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**LoLWithBuddies/src/main/java/com/ucll/LoLWithBuddies/db/RelationalLeagueDB:**

```
package com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.db;

import com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.domain.League;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author Christophe
 */
public class RelationalLeagueDB implements LeagueDB {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private EntityManager manager;

    public RelationalLeagueDB(String name) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(name);
    }

    @Override
    public League get(long id) throws DBException {
        try {
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();
            League league = manager.find(League.class, id);
            if (league == null) {
                throw new DBException("League not found");
            }
            return league;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DBException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<League> getAll() throws DBException {
        try {
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();
            Query query = manager.createQuery("select l from League l");
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DBException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(League league) throws DBException {
        try {

            manager = factory.createEntityManager();

            //update in memory reflected to database inside transaction
            League leagueInDB = manager.find(League.class, league.getId());

            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            leagueInDB.setName(league.getName());
            manager.flush();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DBException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) throws DBException {
        try {
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();
            League league = manager.find(League.class, id);
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.remove(league);
            manager.flush();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DBException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            // manager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(League item) throws DBException {
        try {
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.persist(item);
            manager.flush();
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DBException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void closeConnection() throws DBException {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml** for persistence project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ucll</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoLWithBuddies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**pom.xml** for web project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ucll</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoLWithBuddies-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>LoLWithBuddies-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ucll</groupId>
            <artifactId>LoLWithBuddies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Example controller where I autowire my Service from my domain project in my web app. This service holds the **RelationalLeagueDB** class:

**LoLWithBuddies-web/src/main/java/com/ucll/LoLWithBuddies/controller/LeagueController.java**

```
package com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.controller;

import com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.domain.League;
import com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.service.Service;
import com.ucll.lolwithbuddies.service.ServiceException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author Christophe
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/league")
public class LeagueController {

    @Autowired
    private Service service; 
    private boolean update=false;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLeagues() throws ServiceException {

        List<League> leagues = service.getAllLeagues();
        return new ModelAndView("leagues", "leagues", leagues);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getNewForm() {
        update=false;
        League newLeague = new League();
        return new ModelAndView("leagueform", "leagueForm", newLeague);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("leagueForm") League leagueForm, BindingResult result) throws ServiceException {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "leagueform";
        }

        if(update) {
            service.updateLeague(leagueForm);
        } else {
            service.addLeague(leagueForm);
        }
        update=false;
        return "redirect:/league";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEditForm(@PathVariable long id) throws ServiceException {
        update=true;
        return new ModelAndView("leagueform", "leagueForm", service.getLeague(id));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}/delete", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getDeleteConfirmation(@PathVariable long id) throws ServiceException {
        return new ModelAndView("leaguedeleteconfirm", "delete", service.getLeague(id));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String delete(@ModelAttribute("delete") League toDelete) throws ServiceException {

        service.deleteLeague(toDelete.getId());

        return "redirect:/league";
    }
}
```

The service bean is configured as such in a Java-based config:

```
@Bean(name = "service", destroyMethod = "closeConnection")
    public Service service() throws ServiceException {
        Service bean = new LeagueService("JPA");
        return bean;
    }
```

Notice I can pass an argument to this service (JPA or local). I want to use the JPA for my production code but to test I can pass the local argument to use an in memory Map repository, which works fine.

Anyone who can point me out in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem. As I said, the application works without errors when I run the application the first time. However, the next times when I try to rerun my application after the first time, say because I have made some changes and had to rebuild, GlassFish, the server my application is deployed on, does NOT redeploy my application, and an old version is kept on the server, an old context, and as such my Entities are an 'old version of themself'. In a way, it looks like my destroyMethod on Service is not called.

When I force undeploy my application, restart the server, and then rerun my application, it will work. However, I have to do this manually for the moment. Looking into maven-glassfish-plugin now to do this automatically.